# Create smallest possible FreeBSD drive image

Tags: ssd, dd, disk-image

greetings from Rotterdam in the Netherlands.

I have a challenge. I need to distribute drive images for installation on typical hardware. The development box has a 120Gb SSD. Installed is FreeBSD 11.2-p15.The OS itself shows a drive usage of 4% (approx 2Gb). When creating the image from the SSD with my Macbook (dd in terminal) it creates a nice image of 120Gb. When GZIPing this image with the highest compression level (9) it never gets below 30Gb. But it must be smaller to fit on an USB-flash drive for distribution. Before creating the image a have deleted all junk from the OS like logs, temps en update files. Also did a fsck. There is no encryption on the OS going on.

Do I miss something?  How do I get the image as small as possible?

Thanks for thinking this over...  regards,  Aad

Comment: If you only need files copied, consider using Rsync instead? Using DD keeps the zero bytes, and some may be left after compression too.

Comment: No, unfortunately. I need the complete drive imaged including all system partitions for booting...  I need to flash completely empty SSD's with this image from an USB-thumbdrive.